# Meta tag to go back to previous page

Tags: javascript, html, http, cross-browser, client-server

I need to use the meta tag to go back to the previous page. I read somewhere firefox and IE stopped the use of javascript within meta tags for security purposes. What other alternatives can I use that only require client side scripting like javascript or using html.

This is my code:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="5; URL=javascript:history.back();">
```

It works fine on Safari but not on Firefox and Internet Explorer

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this?

Comment: I need it to go to a certain page for a second and then go the previous page... like when you log in.. i want it to say you are logged in and then go to the previous page

Comment: That would be a waste of 5 seconds. Just refresh the current page immediately.

Comment: Just create a new div that says "You're logged in" and remove it after 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do this would be creating a div which includes your messages and you can hide it after a certain time other than that there are no solutions due to Firefox and IE security purposes